# Can banks "create" Bitcoin

Tags: finance

I have a stupid question. Could a commercial bank creates Bitcoins the way it "creates" money if it was allowed to make loans in Bitcoins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They cannot create more tokens because number of Bitcoins is limited   by the code (only 21 million of bitcoins can be ever mined). However, they can increase money supply of bitcoins via lending.

For example, if someone deposits 100 Bitcoins in a private bank and a bank is not forced by regulation or market self-regulation to keep 100% reserve, then they could lend some of that deposit. Let us say they would lend 50BTC and kept 50BTC as a reserve.

Now there is 150BTC in circulation. The original depositor still has 100BTC on his/hers deposit account but now there is also 50BTC loan. This makes total money supply of BTC 150 even if there are only 100 tokens.

Comment: That is not how fractional reserve banking works. See McLeay et al.

Comment: @Mick you don’t know what you are talking about.. This is one way how fractional reserve generally works you should read McLeay yourself because you clearly do not understand the paper.

Comment: https://www.hks.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/centers/mrcbg/programs/senior.fellows/2019-20%20fellows/BanksCannotLendOutReservesAug2013_%20(002).pdf

Comment: @Mick 1. The mechanism in that non-peer reviewed ‘paper’ is not the same as in McLeavy et al. 2. The paper says that that when loans are made central bank has to supply reserves. For Bitcoin this is not possible long term since central banks cannot create Bitcoins the same way as they can reserves. 3. The paper seems to promote the fringe MMT view of the matter

Comment: The concept of fractional reserve banking is only relevant to this question if the bank sector can create liabilities (bitcoin deposits) that exchange at par with the reserve asset (digital evidence of bitcoin). The bank can only create evidence of bitcoin via mining or must trade value for bitcoin to secure bitcoin for making loans. The bank cannot create bitcoin via keystroke entries in its digital ledger as it can via the franchise that permits banks to expand the elastic money supply in the domestic currency. So i would say banks cannot create bitcoin by making bitcoin loans.

Comment: @SystemTheory if what you say would be correct then gold standard fractional reserve system could never have existed. Empirically west had about 200 years experience with fractional reserve gold standard so you cannot be correct.

Comment: Gold is a non-financial asset. Fiat means "by decree". When a State or other human customs decree or act as if gold is money this means some quantity and quality of gold is given a unit name (e.g., dollar) and symbol (e.g., $). Next banks keep gold in the vault and issue paper banknotes that exchange for gold dollars. Now banks have issued a legal liability, using the unit name and symbol, and the bearer of banknotes holds a financial asset. If payments clear by check or banknotes then bank liabilities become money and bank loans increase money supply. Bitcoin is not created as bank liability.

Comment: 1. Fractional reserve system was used before paper money. Even before banknotes mints lent out deposited gold. 2. bitcoin is literally not a fiat money but fiduciary money.  3. You are not even using word money in its economic meaning, money does not need to be a liability. A rock someone owns is perfectly capable of being a money without being a liability

Comment: Non-financial assets (gold, bitcoin) can be used as means of payment (money). Banks cannot create such non-financial assets. Gold is a tangible metal whose total supply is limited by physical mining and refinement of gold. Bitcoin is an intangible asset whose total supply is limited by the bitcoin algorithm. Liabilities can also become customary means of payment (money). Under "free banking" gold standard banks or non-banks could issue paper notes as liabilities payable in gold at their gold window. If such liabilities circulate as means of payment they are money. Banks do not create bitcoin.

Comment: They do not need to create them, bank can lend physical gold deposited in it expanding money supply, this does not require banknotes. Pre 17 century banks operated without bank notes

Comment: If gold or bitcoin are used as non-financial assets and means of payment (money) then let this be generalized as non-financial money NFM. If nonbanks transfer NFM to banks then this reduces NFM outside banks and increases bank reserves held in the form of NFM. Banks cannot increase the money supply of NFM by lending because they must first borrow or obtain those NFM from a source outside the bank sector. Banks can lend dollars or other fiat currency against bitcoin collateral. They cannot create bitcoin by lending bitcoin. Banks might create monetary liabilities that trade at par with bitcoin.

Comment: you do not understand the definition of money supply but in economics deposits counts as a part of money supply. If someone deposits 100btc into bank and bank takes 50 of those btcs and transfers them to some another account as loan money supply of bitcion literally by definition will be 150. The deposit account is still showing 100btc even if bank actually does not physically have 100 btc but only 50

Comment: I do understand bank accounting mechanics and ownership claims under the rule of law. Let the token metal coin or digital evidence of coin be recognized as a non-financial asset that serves as customary means of payment. This is non-financial money (NFM). If I own 150 NFM, and lend 100 NFM to you, or deposit it in the bank, then you or the bank owe me 100 NFM and I own the other 50 NFM. There is still just 150 NFM. If bank lends my 100 NFM deposit then bank borrower takes possession of 100 NFM. The bank holds a financial asset equal to the 100 NFM repayment note. The total is still 150 NFM.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rule of law. If someone deposits 100 BTC into a bank there is in economy 100 BTC worth of the deposit. If now bank takes 50 of that 100BTC deposit and lends it as a 50 BTC loan and keeps 50 as a reserve the BTC money supply is 150 regardless that only 100 BTC were mined because money supply is, among other things, sum of deposits and money in circulation and deposit is still 100 even if bank took 50 BTC from that deposit

Comment: Law is the basis for ownership and control of scarce resources. It is also the basis for accounting customs. Physical supply of gold coin does not increase, because it cannot increase, when a bank makes a physical loan of gold coin. Instead the bank holds a note and the borrower takes the right to hold or spend the gold coin. If the bank makes the loan via the issue and expansion of its own banknotes or deposits, and if customers clear payment using the bank's liabilities, then the bank can and does expand the money supply. The bank does not create gold and it does not create BTC.

Comment: Nobody claims that physical supply of coins increases, the claim is that the money supply increases. Just google definition of money supply in economics. Also law is not basis for accounting customs google history of accounting. Historically basis for accounting was record keeping not law.

Comment: The question is whether banks create BTC? The answer is no because banks do not have the power to create or destroy BTC via the act of borrowing and lending. However if the banks issue BTC liabilities, similar to gold banknotes or modern bank deposits, and if the bank customers transfer ownership of these financial assets to clear payment, then the bank sector would have the power to increase the BTC money supply, via fractional reserve banking, but still could not create BTC. This is a direct analogy to the gold supply and the increase of bank liabilities trading at par with gold currency.

Comment: @SystemTheory please read the question. The question is not if banks can literally create Bitcoin. The author literally says that the question is if banks can “create” money (if you are not aware of English language usage of sneer quotes “” please google that as well). Also the question literally asks if banks can create more bitcoins the same using loans not if it can mine more bitcoins. 100btc account is still economically considered 100BTC even if bank has only 50 BTC in its crypto vault

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin by saying 1Muflon1's answer should be accepted.  It is correct.  The only reason that I am answering is that there appears to be some confusion by others about how this would work.  In addition, there is a fascinating implication to your question that seems to have been missed.

Let us also dispose of Bitcoin as a currency and replace it with NewCoin.  My technical interest in this question stemmed from its statistical properties.  I will explain why we need to dispose of Bitcoin.  It has undesirable properties.

The use of privately issued token money is not new.  George Selgin's excellent book "Good Money" describes the token money created while Isaac Newton was Master of the Mint.  If we ignore Newton's scientific work and instead focus on his religious beliefs and ideas around the Mint, he is downright weird.

His unusual ideas created a shortage of coinage, especially in denominations small enough to pay workers or to purchase daily goods.  Button makers produced tokens.  If you gathered enough tokens, they would redeem them for money from the Mint.  I think that may be what is fueling cryptocurrencies.  With the US Government's intense tracking of all but the smallest transactions, there is a shortage of non-cash anonymous transaction media.  Both the US and the world had an abundance of it once.  Of course, one could infer that many of those transactions are illicit from at least some governments' perspectives.

The problem with Bitcoin is that the total number of coins that could be mined is too small to cover the system's needs.  It also appears to have a winner's curse problem.  Cryptocurrencies are more valuable to some people than to others.  The coins will tend to move to people whose preferences would give the coins higher reservation prices.  That is not a desirable property for a currency or a medium of exchange.

Currencies do not need banks to exist.  The money system on the Island of Yap has always existed without needing to resort to banks.  The coins exist in adequate supply for the purposes for which they have always been used.  I have not checked for several years, but they do not appear to have been supplanted by a major currency for local use except for imported goods.  A single Yap coin can easily weigh a ton.

Because the coins are so large, they are nearly immobile.  Their value is based on how difficult moving them into place was.  They are also based on a distributed ledger.  A coin is transferred by making the community know who the new owner was and what was exchanged.  The coins' sizes make them impossible to counterfeit, a physical equivalence to encryption.  A two-ton object sitting on the top of a steep hill is not going to be faked and replaced.

Cryptocurrencies have had physical analogs for hundreds of years, even in the United States.  What is interesting to me is the implication of your question.

So let us again assume we have a new cryptocurrency called the NewCoin.  It comes into existence like other currencies but in smaller denominations.  The coin is traded, but it seems to be traded roughly around a steady-state value.  Because it is used as a real medium of exchange, banks get interested and offer to make loans and take deposits.  Remember that its unique value is that it is decentralized and anonymous.

How do banks get into the NewCoin lending business?

First, they have to set aside capital.  Current reserve policies are based on loan riskiness, but we will use the older gold-standard policies.  Banks will first buy a base of NewCoins that depends on what they think the demand for NewCoin loans will be.  It is the loan demand that is key.  The first loans will be to the players that value these loans the most.  The last loans will be to those that value them the least.

The banks will make their initial loans, but they want these coins back to make more loans, so they will have to offer interest-bearing accounts denominated in NewCoins.  The interest rate must be enough to pull those coins back out of the market.  Banks will have to offer and accept coins at par.  That could cause the coin exchanges to collapse.  Banks do not discount coins when you go to the bank.  When you ask for a dollar, they give you a dollar.

People would move their NewCoin to the banks if the exchanges really came under pressure.  Most people buying cryptocurrencies do not care a whit about the distributed ledger feature.  Decentralization is a hobbyist's love, not the public's.  Suppose you could own a cryptocurrency's value without any risk of losing on the bid-ask spread and earn interest on it.  Would you care that the banks are now centralizing the real coins?

The banks would pay interest in order to make the next round of loans.  Of course, at some point, they would reach an equilibrium level of loans, deposits, and interest rates, but that is down the line a bit.  As banks saw other banks making a profit, they would devote more and more capital to it.  The currency's value would tend to stabilize because banks were offering to exchange it at par.

The primary parties that would not participate in the bank money would be those seeking anonymity.  They would also be easier to identify for law enforcement authorities because most owners are now getting interest on their NewCoin.  Some outside transactions would still be necessary to discipline the banks, just as gold and silver did circulate around the world during periods where we have used metal standards.

The non-bank bid-ask spread would have to widen because most parties would use the banks' costless exchange.  Banks would probably totally internalize any mining aspects to prevent theft and other related issues.  The only miners would be banks.  They would either regulate the others out of existence by holding the majority of the money and changing the charter or use their raw power to shut down external competition.  They could take away the value of being a miner.

If a cryptocurrency could be produced in adequate volume to allow a steady-state valuation, even if it did drift over more extended periods of time, and banks offered loans and deposits of it, then its value as a source of anonymous, decentralized money would vanish.  Under a fractional reserve system, banks would internalize the exchange, transfer, mining, and de facto ownership of it.  We would still have to have externalized ownership of individual coins, but the exchange could be forced to happen through bank servers at a discount or premium.

To maintain external transactions, a person going to a store to buy something that paid in NewCoin would electronically transfer the NewCoin to the merchant.  If all the mining was done by the banks, the banks would have brought it inside even though it was "external."  Alternatively, the government could grant itself a statutory monopoly on mining all cryptocurrency transactions to protect the banks and prevent conflicts of interest.  Within bank transfers, such as when a depositor buys something from a merchant that is also a deposit at the same bank, would drive down mining costs because there is no reason to transfer the underlying NewCoin.  The movement would instead happen between line items of the bank's ledger.  There is no reason for the bank to transfer it to itself.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is yes. If someone wanted to borrow say 0.1BTC from bank A, then the bank would freshly create an IOU of 0.1BTC and add that to your account. This IOU would be spendable (this may require government decree). So now the Bitcoin money supply has grown by 0.1BTC.

If you used the IOU of 0.1BTC to buy a car from someone than had an account at bank B, then your account at A would diminish by .1BTC while simultaneously the sellers account at B would increase by 0.1BTC and bank A would have to transfer its 0.1(real)BTC to bank B. Now bank B has the asset of 0.1(real)BTC and a liability of owing the seller 0.1BTC.

Given this example one might imagine that the banks would be limited to only lend out (i.e. create IOUs) for as many bitcoin as they possessed originally. But in a more realistic example bank A and B may be making thousands of such loans and there may be thousands of transfers of spendable-IOUs-of-bitcoins between them. The two banks would only need to transfer the *net* balancing amount of real bitcoin to settle between them at the end of the day. Just statistically, this net transfer will likely be a small fraction of the total money transferred. This means that the total value of bank IOUs of bitcoin can rise to be a large multiple of the amount of real bitcoin held by the banks in the first place.

I have told a story so far in which banks hold some real bitcoin themselves (like reserves) and transfer them directly between each other. Regulators might optionally insist that banks hold their reserves of real bitcoin in accounts with the central bank.

Whether any of this should, or is likely to, happen in practice is a whole other story. This answer was just to illustrate the mechanics in a way analogous to the way [fractional reserve banking](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/quarterly-bulletin/2014/money-creation-in-the-modern-economy.pdf) works today.

Comment: It is impossible for bitcoin fractional reserve banking to operate this way. 1. If you would actually read McLeavy et al (2014) and sources cited therein pass the headline you would discover that is how US fractional reserve system operates since circa 2008 when Fed decided to give Private banks interest for reserves at Fed moving into system of perpetual excess reserves. That can only work if Fed can perpetually pay private banks bitcoins, which is impossible since while Fed can create more dollars it would not be able to perpetually create more bitcoins. Bitcoins fractional reserve, if it

Comment: could exist, would almost certainly work like fractional reserve system under gold standard, where this was not feasible

Comment: @1muflon1 Fractional reserve has existed in the past without a federal reserve. Banks frequently went bankrupt and depositors lost all their money. But it still existed.

Comment: @user253751 it didn’t exist in a way as described by McLeavy et al. The McLeavy et al describe how US fractional reserve operated between 2008-2019, and there is no way how that particular execution of fractional reserve could be applied to Bitcoin. Bitcoin could have the same sort of fractional reserve gold standard had but that’s not the fractional reserve system described by McLeavy

Comment: @user253751 this answer claims that Bitcoin fractional reserve could work as described by McLeavy et al. Did you even read the answer or are you just trolling?

Comment: @1muflon1 oh, the last link. It looks accurate to me. Other than the references to the central bank (which still exists in Bitcoin, in the form of an algorithm which does not care about price stability) do you care to explain why the money creation part of the paper is impossible with Bitcoin? Would the balance sheets of Bitcoin banks not follow the arrangement described in the paper?

Comment: @user253751 because it requires arbitrary amount of excess reserves. That’s impossible with Bitcoin with its cap on MB, see first two comments

Comment: @1muflon1 I don't see why an arbitrarily large and growing amount of excess reserves is required for fractional reserve banking according to the paper.

Comment: @user253751 then go and read the paper

Comment: @1muflon1 Can you tell me which part of the paper I need to pay particular attention to?

Comment: @user253751 p 15-21

Comment: @1muflon1 More specifically? It does talk about how central banks can use monetary policy. It doesn't say they *have to* use good monetary policy.

Comment: @user253751 why dont you read the paper? you clearly did not read it as it does not discuss good or bad monetary policy. it discusses the workings of US fractional reserve system post 2008 it does not talk at all about good or bad monetary policy

Comment: @1muflon1 and where in those workings is a central bank creating unbounded amounts of base money a requirement for this kind of fractional reserve system to exist?

Comment: @user253751 as described in the paper in this particular system CB has to always supply reserves when bank request them. They can’t say no, otherwise the system wouldn’t work. This is impossible when the currency is arbitrary limited. This can only work if CB can create reserves at will according to bank demand otherwise the system won’t work.

Comment: @1muflon1 "Central banks do not typically choose a quantity of reserves to bring about the desired short-term interest rate.(4) Rather, they focus on prices — setting interest rates." - okay, but they could, and the rest of the ideas in the paper would still apply in that case?

Comment: @user253751 1. no in that case the paper would no longer apply, that would be the pre-2008 Fractional Reserve. 2. Actually, even the pre-2008 fractional reserve would not work because that also requires CB to have ability to create unlimited reserves. The sort of 18 century gold based fractional reserve system would work with bitcoin not the modern ones